# Laravel session Flash Message Not working

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Session message is not working i tried this code and many fix available online 
Here id my store function `

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'      =>'required',
            'username'  =>'required',
            'email'     =>'required',
            'address'   =>'required',
            'likes'     =>'required',
            'gender'        =>'required'

        ]);

        $input = $request->all();

        Contacts::create($input);

        Session::put('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

And Retrieving by this code

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
        </div>
@endif
```

Comment: what version of Laravel 5 ?

Comment: btw you can just write `return back()->with('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');`

Answer (score 22):

**I resolved issue with laravel 6.x**

As soon as I moved `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` and `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` from web `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware` in **`app\Http\Kernel.php`**  everything started working as expected.

Comment: I tried this but then it just brings 419 status when you try to login and authenticate

Comment: @dark_illusion_909099 this is what i have done for simple and auth module independent app. you may need to do some work around for your problem in this context.

Comment: After hours of searching, finally it solved my problem.

Comment: @Ningappa Thanks brother you save my life. :)

Comment: My problem was that I was using redirect(url('')) rather than simply specifying the route

Comment: I tried this but not working. It seems issue something different.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me, however in my case  StartSession::class and ShareErrorsFromSession::class appeared in both $middlewareGroups and $middleware.  I suspect this occurred when Sanctum was installed and setup for XHR.

Answer (score 7):

I Resolved the Issue with laravel 5.2.

I was having route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [ 'web','auth']], function () {
.......
}
```

So Removed the web middle ware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
.......
}
```

and its start working

Analysis: By default Laravel Add web Middleware.
check by php artisan route:list it shows web, web,auth .

so by defining it again redirect two time for the web middleware.

Comment: Had the same issue. Anyone know where the web middleware gets defined as default? What if I have a route where I don't want the web middleware to be used?

Comment: Okay. Not too hard to find. With the 'new' update also came a RouteServiceProvider where this gets set.

Answer (score 4):

**I RESOLVED the issue with laravel 5.2.**

I was having all the routes inside this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
```

I remove it because when I used the command php artisan route:list in the Name Middleware column the "web" shows to times: web, web.

If you have AUTH replace by:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
```

Also I delete a duplicate route (in **routes**.php). Now I just have:

```
Route::resource('/publicaciones', 'PublicacionesController');
```

**My controller**:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Saved!');
```

**My view**:

```
  @if(Session::has('success'))
          <div class="alert alert-success">
              {{ Session::get('success') }}
          </div>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

have you include the following namespace

```
use Session;
```

instead of the following code

```
 Session::put('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');
```

use

```
 Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');
```

in instead to

```
return redirect()->back();
```

try using

```
 return redirect()->route('your route');
```

Comment: use Session; is already included and Session::falsh is not working for me

Comment: instead of return redirect()->back(); could you please try  return redirect()->route( 'your route here' ); i have updated my answer

Comment: `redirect()->route('your route');` is not necessary. `redirect()->back();` should work absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1):

When the validation fails, no further code is executed and the previous page is loaded again. This is the reason why session message is not working. In order to check for any validation errors use the following code snippet at the top of your blade file.

```
@if ($errors->any())
  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
      <strong>{{ $error }}</strong>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for this forum. I encounter this problem, I've been different sites searching for the right solution but none works. Here's my case, I'm using `v6.0`, and I put the route inside `routes\api.php`.

I think there is difference of putting the `route` to the right place or file, can't explain more.

Here's **how I solved**, I transfer the route from `routes\api.php` to `routes\web.php` and thats it after so many researching I now successfully display the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');
Session::save();
return redirect()->back();
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This will work in case "Session" fails to display errors in your blade view.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```