# Laravel session flash messages are not showing on production (Laravel Forge)

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I have a Laravel Blade form that is not displaying flash session error messages on my [production site](https://employbl.com/candidates). It was previously giving 419 error response "Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again. on production laravel". I was able to clear that so the form submits by clearing the cache and composer dump-autoload.

This is the form to display the sessions. Works locally, I am on L5.7.9.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('candidates.store') }}" class="form">
    @csrf

    @if(session('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (session('login_error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ session('login_error') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            Woops had some problems saving
        </div>
    @endif
```

In my **.env** file I have:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DOMAIN=employbl.com
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Then in the controller store method I have:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $request->validate([
        'first_name'         => 'required',
        'last_name'          => 'required',
        'email'              => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'linkedin_url'       => 'required|url',
        'phone_number'       => 'required',
        'work_authorization' => 'required',
        'city'               => 'required',
        'state'              => 'required'
    ]);

    $candidate         = new User($request->all());
    $candidate->active = false;
    $candidate->save();

    return redirect()->route('candidates.landing')->with('message', 'Successfully applied to join Employbl network!');
}
```

For routes I do not have a route group:

```
Route::get('/candidates', 'CandidateController@landing')->name('candidates.landing');
Route::post('/candidates', 'CandidateController@store')->name('candidates.store');
```

php artisan route:list shows that I am only using the web middleware once:

```
|        | POST     | candidates                                                                                 | candidates.store            | App\Http\Controllers\CandidateController@store                             | web                                                                                                                                                                               |
```

The flash messages are working locally, but when I submit the form on production (deployed with Laravel Forge) the form submits but no flash messages are displayed. What can I do to make the session messages appear on production and why is this happening?

Comment: Please check of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648930/laravel-session-flash-message-not-working) helps

Comment: Also did you do `php artisan migrate` to have a `sessions` table on production **if** your session driver is `database`?

Comment: Updated to show my routes info, not issue there. My session driver on prod is `file` so don't have a sessions table. Would using a sessions table possibly help with this?

Comment: Just checking if the normal login works? Like not flash messages but normal session? Might be file permissions for `storage/framework/sessions`. Mostly check permissions of `storage` folder?

Comment: Okay I updated database to use sessions table. The session messages are still not showing when I submit the form. I am able to login and logout from the app fine though. With using session db table would file permissions still be the issue?

Comment: Where are you setting `session('message')` and `session('login_error')` or those are validation erros?

Comment: Session message is validation error. Even if it wasn't set I'd be hoping `$errors->any()` would catch errors. As it is now when I click submit even with no input I don't get any flashes: https://employbl.com/candidates

Comment: I just realised you passing `message` using `with()`. So you can use that  using `$message` directly

Comment: The flash data will exists until the next request, you're sending the message to a "route" and them calling the view in this route, so tem data will not exists on the view.
Try to access the $message on the "landing" function

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some methods (has) to check if you have a session with that name and (get) to get the value.

```
@if(session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session::get('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (session::has('login_error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ session::get('login_error') }}
        </div>
    @endif



    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            Woops had some problems saving
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Hey Vidal, this is not the issue. Using session helper like I have above is fine: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#using-the-session. It works locally as well so I think it's something with session config on my server. Thank you for the input though

Comment: Got it, I will do an dd on the blade to see if we have a value on the session while on the blade template.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the problem ?

```
     return redirect()
            ->route('candidates.landing')
            ->with('message', 'Successfully applied to join Employbl network!');
    // I think with takes [](array) so, 
     return redirect()
            ->route('candidates.landing')
            ->with(['message' => 'Successfully applied to join Employbl network!']);
  //
  //
  // But why are't you doing like this 
  //
  //
  return back()->with([
          'message' => 'Successfully applied to join Employbl network!'
        ]);
  //
  //
  //
  // And yes Session::has('message') or \Session::has('message') is a good way to check in the blade
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to run `php artisan cache:clear` to get rid of existing session information. More info here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/419-error-when-submitting-form-in-production-sorry-your-session-has-expired-please-refresh-and-try-again#reply=494157