# PHP Laravel session flash alert message not showing

Tags: php, laravel

In my `laravel`-app users can check a checkbox on the contact form if they want to subscribe for a newsletter. When the checkbox is checked and the submit the form, there is a check in the controller, if the user already is subscribed and if so, a flash alert/message should appear with something like 'You are already subscribed'.
Now, the check itself works, but the flash/alert message is not displaying and I don't know why.

in my view:

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
       <p>{{ \Session::get('success') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
@if (\Session::has('failure'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <p>{{ \Session::get('failure') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
 <div class="contact-form" id="contact">
     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contact.store') }}">
     ...
     </form>
 </div>
```

and in my controller:

```
// when the checkbox is checked!

if (!empty(request()->newsletter)) {
    if (!Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
        Newsletter::subscribePending(request()->email);

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with('success', 'Thanks for subscribing!');

    } else {

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with('failure', 'You are already subscribed');

    }
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: why do you have the backslash before the session, it shouldn't be there

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648930/laravel-session-flash-message-not-working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be using the session class, rather than the session helper laravel injects on the service container.

If you're using Laravel 5.8, session in blade is a helper function as per the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

**An example**

```
Route::post('user/profile', function () {
    // Update the user's profile...

    return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
});
```

So use the helper function in blade like this:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

**NB: This will only work if you are using a page submit. If it's a javascript submit you may need to refresh the page to get the alert to show up.**

Comment: @ST80 are you using Laravel 5.8? The docs would be wrong if not!

Comment: @ST80 can you tell us a bit more about what is not working? It's hard to help you if you just tell us it's failed, and not how or why or what behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: hmm, If I hit the network tab, the redirected route is listed and when I click on the preview tab, there is a raw version of the page -> with the message ....

Comment: Are you submitting the update via a form submit, or an javascript call of some sort?
If it's a whole-page based form-post, the session flash will occur on the page. If it's asynchronous the flash gets wasted on the invisible call.

Comment: Yes, the form gets submitted with javascript - ok, then thats the issue :-s

Comment: Potentially simply using javascript to reload the page might fix this... try a simple `location.reload()` for now?

Comment: I've updated my answer, since we've kinda solved the problem here I think... hope you can accept it as the answer again? :D

Comment: Im using laravel 5.8! My validation errors were inside the session!! Different from the docs lol

Answer (score 1):

If the above answers are not getting you the desired result you should check if your request gets through the validation.

Try to dd() the request after the validation and see if you get the results from your request.

If the problem lies with the flashing of the session this is how I like to do it.

```
if (!empty(request()->newsletter)) {
    if (!Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
        Newsletter::subscribePending(request()->email);
        Session::flash('message', 'Thanks for subscribing!');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
        return redirect()->route('contact.create');

    } else {
        Session::flash('message', 'You are already subscribed!');
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
        return redirect()->route('contact.create');

    }
}
```

Then in the view I use this code block for the message.

```
  @if(Session::has('message'))
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-6">
              <p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ 
                Session::get('message') }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  @endif
```

Dont forget the reference to the session on the top of your controller!

```
use Session;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, session flash just working on form submit and return redirect().

I working on Laravel 5.8

-Controller

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Thanks for subscribing']);
    }
}
```

- Route

```php
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/test', 'HomeController@test');
```

- View

```html
@if ($message = session('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should pass value as array `['success'=>'Thanks for subscribing!'`, try this.

```
if (!empty(request()->newsletter)) {
    if (!Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
        Newsletter::subscribePending(request()->email);

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with(['success'=>'Thanks for subscribing!']);

    } else {

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with(['failure'=> 'You are already subscribed']);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
       <p>{{Session::get('success') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
@if (Session::has('failure'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <p>{{ Session::get('failure') }}</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

i love to do it this way, you can try it

```
@if (session('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('success') }}
                </div>
            @endif
@if (session('failure'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    {{ session('failure') }}
                </div>
            @endif
```

then edit your controller

```
if (!empty(request()->newsletter)) {
    if (!Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
        Newsletter::subscribePending(request()->email);

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with(['success'=> 'Thanks for subscribing!']);

    } else {

        return redirect()->route('contact.create')->with(['failure'=>'You are already subscribed']);

    }
}
```

this way it will return an array and not an object

Comment: then the problem is from your controller, try to return a value from your controller and dd() it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values with `WithMessage` instead of `with` so in the controller you would redirect like this `return back()->withMessage('Thanks for subscribing');`then in the blade you can access the message with

```
@if (session('message'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session('message') }}
   </div>
@endif
```

And for the error message I would personally use the Validator of laravel it self so you can access the errors like this

```
@if($errors->any())
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <li> {{ $error }} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

also like mention by @Niklesh Raut you can also make it an array and access them like an `@if` statement in the blade

Comment: have you tried `return redirect()->route('contact.create')->withMessage('Thanks for subscribing!');` and then access them in the blade with `@if(session('message'))`

Comment: Yes, but with not luck. If I hit the network tab, I get the redirected route and on the preview there is a raw version of the page -> with the message ....

Comment: have you also tried `return back()` also can you say which version of laravel your using and does a `dd()` or `die()` end up on that page?