# ValidationException Error Message did not working after Upgrading Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, exception, laravel-5.8

After upgrading Laravel 5.7 to 5.8 my Validation Error message doesnt seems to work after redirect

```
$validator = Model::validate($request);
if ($validator->fails()) {
 throw ValidationException::withMessages($validator->messages()->toArray());
}
```

I try do `dd($request->all());` It does send the array field that I required
and I was not sure what the real problem cause laravel community doesnt seems to have problem with this after searching throughout article

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer from Ningappa, remove or move the

`'\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class'`
`'\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class'`

from $middlewaregroup and place it under $middleware, sometimes it is already there then just removed it.

[Laravel session Flash Message Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648930/laravel-session-flash-message-not-working/59420073#59420073)