# Laravel 8 Flash Session not working on Request

Tags: laravel, session, flash-message

I wonder in my application can't show flash message. I have tried many solutions on stackoverflow but my problem is not solved.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class DebugController extends Controller
{ 

public function get()
    {
        // Visit direct page flash session is working
        // Eg: localhost/debug/get
        // But if I send request all flash sessions are not working
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('success', 'Working session on visit direct page!');
    }
    
public function post(Request $request)
    {    
        // All flash sessions are not working
        session()->flash('anything', 'Session not working!');

        // Working session
        session()->put('message', 'Working session!');

        // Session not working, is 'success' key reserved?
        session()->put('success', 'Session not working!');
        
        return Redirect::route('home')->with('anything', 'Session not working!'); // Session not working
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('debug/get', 'DebugController@get');
Route::post('debug/post', 'DebugController@post');
```

View:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif


// Working session
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
    {{ session()->forget('message') }}
@endif
```

I have tried to modify middle ware in Kernel from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420073/4255535) but still not working

```
Laravel Version: 8.x.x
PHP Version: 7.4.x
```

Comment: Show us how you are *using* the flash data, in your view. It doesn't display automatically; that's your responsibility.

Comment: @ceejayoz I have added my blade view

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do `Session::has('anything')` in your view instead of `Session::has('success')`.

The first parameter is the key that can be accessed with `has` or `get`.

If the above is already done, you might need to use the Facade: `Session::flash('anything','content');`

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004310/in-laravel-the-best-way-to-pass-different-types-of-flash-messages-in-the-sessio).

---

In case you want to remove the Session data
you have to use `flush` instead of `flash()`.

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#deleting-data)

Comment: I am trying to create a [Flash Message](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data), not deleting.